# iOS, How to check whether the user likes a facebook page or not?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

How to check whether the user likes a facebook page or not in an iPhone app?

I know that I need `"user_likes"` permission. what else should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't like a page on Facebook. The best way to achieve that is to load the page inside a uiwebview and later you can check whether the user liked the page or not.

Comment: how i check that user like that page or not

Comment: @MuzamilHassan, check this http://life-optimized.blogspot.com/2013/08/check-if-facebook-page-is-liked-using.html