# Swift 3.0, How to check whether the user like a facebook page or not?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to check user like a facebook page or not?

Here, 
My code is,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let likeButton = FBSDKLikeControl()
    likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/IntelIndia/"
    likeButton.center = self.view.center
    likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.boxCount
    likeButton.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = FBSDKLikeControlHorizontalAlignment.right
    self.view.addSubview(likeButton)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.likeActionPerformed), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "FBSDKLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification"), object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func likeActionPerformed(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("\(notification.object)")
}
```

When I execute this code I got "notification.object" like this

```
Printing description of notification:
NSConcreteNotification 0x7d940e20 {name =  FBSDKLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification; object = <FBSDKLikeActionController: 0x7d89cea0>; userInfo = {
animated = 1;
}}
```

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page

Comment: @Amanpreet This is not a vaild answer as per my question, And It's in PHP not in Swift

Comment: Oops! I apologies.

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719701/ios-how-to-check-whether-the-user-likes-a-facebook-page-or-not?rq=1

Comment: @Amanpreet Ok, I have checked this link, And I try to implement in my code, But yet I don't understand after my uiwebview loaded how can I check whether the user liked the page or not?

Comment: @Amanpreet Can I like facebook page inside my app? If yes then How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133854/discussion-between-himanshu-patel-and-amanpreet).

Comment: I think you need a page_id too. As you can see http://life-optimized.blogspot.in/2013/08/check-if-facebook-page-is-liked-using.html. But its not in swift.

Comment: @Amanpreet Ok, I try to apply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FBLikeControl callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236655/fblikecontrol-callback)

Comment: @Amanpreet Not working. Nothing happend when I call.

Comment: FYI: Facebook does not allow “like gating” in any way, shape or form any more. You would need user_likes permission - but Facebook will not approve that in review, if you try to get it for this purpose. You have to show the same content to people regardless of whether they liked a specific page or not.

Comment: @CBroe I have alredy prermission of "user_likes ". 


When I click on "Facebook Like" button for particular facebook page my 1 like added successfully, After I call notification method "FBSDKLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification" for response (If page like success or not).

But not working properly. I got response like this,

Printing description of notification:
NSConcreteNotification 0x7d940e20 {name =  FBSDKLikeActionControllerDidUpdateNotification; object = <FBSDKLikeActionController: 0x7d89cea0>; userInfo = {
animated = 1;
}}